# Finitely presented module with localization in free module

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, localization

Let $R$ a commutative ring with unit. Let $M$ a finitely presented $R$-module and let $\mathfrak{p}$ a prime in $R$. Suppose that $M_{\mathfrak{p}}$ is a free module. Prove that there is $a\in R- \mathfrak{p}$ such that $M_a$ is a free module.

Any solution please? I have no ideas...

Comment: I suppose you want $M_a$ is a free $R_a$-module, and $M_P$ is also a free $R_p$-module.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake. I edited